# Sql server difference instead of sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 5 columns :

```
PK_Column, FK_MeterID, Date, Index, Value
```

and I have this query which is working fine :

```
SELECT FK_MeterID,
       sum(Value) as 'Total',
       @p_Month,
       @p_Year
FROM ValuesHistory
WHERE month(Date) = @p_Month
      and year(Date)  = @p_Year
GROUP BY  FK_MeterID
```

However instead of summing the values over a month, I would like to do

a difference of indexes between the last index of the month and the first index of the

month. (It should return the same result)

How can I make this query using a difference ?

Thanks

Comment: Specify "a difference of indexes".

Comment: An index is a value which grows over time , so if I have 4 values : 0,10,10,10 . My corresponding indexes are 0,10,20,30. A sum of those values is 0+10+10+10 = 30 and a difference of indexes is 30-0 = 30

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you were looking for [aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY FK_MeterID
                  ORDER BY Date, PK_Column),
           TOTAL  = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY FK_MeterID),
           MINVAL = MIN(Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY FK_MeterID),
           MAXVAL = MAX(Value)  OVER (PARTITION BY FK_MeterID),
           PK_Column, FK_MeterID, [Date], [Index], Value
    FROM ValuesHistory
    WHERE month(Date) = @p_Month
      AND year(Date)  = @p_Year
)
SELECT DIFFERENCE = MAXVAL - MINVAL, CTE.*
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Hello, nice answer but using min and max will not be correct in my case. Because of technical reasons, the index may be 0 for a few days during the month (communication broken, etc...). I was hoping to avoid to specify the first date and last date of month to get the corresponding index. As i would need to loop through my records to do that.

Comment: on the other hand, using max(date) and min(date) to get the corresponding index would help me. (just thinking aloud)

Comment: @Oliver: I'm not sure if i understand the problem. You are already using the variables `@p_Month` and `@p_Year`. So i have assumed that this selects only a specific month. Hence `MIN` and `MAX`  would select the correct values of the month.

Comment: Hello. Min and Max may not select the correct values of the month because I could have a break in the data I receive like this : index -> 10,000 - 10,100 - 10,200 - 0 (loss of connection with db) - 0 - 10,400 - 10,500 etc. So using Max should be correct but Min will be 0 instead of 10,000